# Jquery Ajax submitting empty textarea text to the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I am trying to insert a `textarea`'s text to my MySQL database, but my problem is when my program tries to submit empty text to the database.

When I remove `e.preventDefault();` it is  working just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
var frm = $('#newsform');

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
            //clear all fields
            $('#newsform').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
            //clear all fields
            $('#newsform').trigger("reset");
        },
    });        
});

<form action="updatenews.php" method="POST" id="newsform">
    <textarea name="news"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: when you remove e.preventDefault it does a normal postback instead of ajax, so assuming you don't want that to happen then leave it in place. Then check your network tab in the browser developer tools and look inside the ajax request to see what was sent in the request body, and whether it matches what you expect

Comment: What do you get if you do `console.log(frm.serialize());` just before the ajax call?

Comment: just before ajax call gave me this

news=

Comment: @ADyson when i see in the network body it is showing news=

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/umsq4oud/ Watch the network tab for that (the request will fail because the target URL doesn't exist but that's not the point, you can see the request body is populated). Maybe something else is interfering with your data, but it's not anything in the code you've posted. What version of jQuery are you using, out of interest?

Comment: @ADyson Now i found the issue, the issue is with the "tinymce wysiwyg editor" i am using it for textarea. If i remove tinymce cdn from the code then all is fine with the data submission. But i want to know why "tinymce wysiwyg" editor is intercepting ajax code? I am using jquery 3.2.1 from cdnjs

Comment: I doubt it's intercepting the ajax, more likely it's changing the markup and making the form difficult to serialise. You should probably check the documentation, I'm sure they will have something about this, it must be a common situation, unless you've configured it incorrectly. We can't see your code for it so it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: I resolved the issue with the tinymce by placing it above the closing body tag and then placed the ajax code in ready function :)

Answer (score -3):

```
var frm = $('#newsform'); 

frm.submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: {'frm':frm},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Submission was successful.');
            console.log(data);
            //clear all fields
                $('#newsform').trigger("reset");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
            //clear all fields
                $('#newsform').trigger("reset");
        },
    });


});
```

Comment: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

getting above error when i tried above code

Comment: `data: {'frm':frm},` er no, why would you submit the whole HTMLElement object? The form _data_ is what's required.